# String = A 5600 2 A 24B9 3 A 4800v 3 A 31 6

Tags: app.xaml

I have one such large string.  I would like the output to be added in list using vb. Net or c#.  I work on the software called uipath. I was known that regex  operations doesn't work. So can help me find solution?

```
A 560 2 (first value in list) 
A 24B9 3 (2nd  value) 
A 4800v 3(3rd  value)
A 31 6
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Please read [ask]. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and what your specific problem is.

Comment: I want to convert the string into list

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one char ('A'), your values start with, you can split by it and add it to your values again:

```
string source = "A 5600 2 A 24B9 3 A 4800v 3 A 31 6";

var list = source.Split(new char[] { 'A' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => "A" + s).ToList();
```

will produce the desired list of values.